# Trying to understand how img = np.zeros((300,512,3), np.uint8) gives us a black window

Tags: python, numpy

I am a naive Python coder so pardon my ignorance.

I wanted to know how does img = np.zeros((300,512,3), np.uint8) generate a black window in OpenCV. Also if someone could help me understand the importance of channels, in my case (300,512,3) '3' is the channel.

I tried googling it out and found https://answers.opencv.org/question/74576/how-does-npzeros-create-a-black-background/ but still am confused!.

Thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: This is not a programming question but a general question on how images and computer graphics. The channels represent the different color components; red, gren, and blue. If they are all zero, you have no colors, which means black.

Comment: I think you should refer to documentation before asking such a question. See the Numpy docs at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/. Please read the help section of this forum about what are appropriate questions and what you should do before asking questions on this forum. As a questioner, it is your responsibility to do some research before asking questions.

Comment: thanks @fmw42 for sharing the document, will go through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
img = np.zeros((300,512,3), np.uint8)
```

creates a 3D array that is 300 rows high, 512 columns wide, and 3 "channels" deep. Each channel corresponds to the amount of red, green, or blue intensity.

```
np.zeros
```

means that this array will be completely filled with 0's.

0 intensity for red, green, and blue translates into a black image.
This type of encoding is called RGB, because each color channel represents the intensity of red, green, or blue.

Comment: Thank you @cynthi8 for such a detailed explanation.